# Value not set to Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have property in Product Class

```
public virtual string IconUrl { get; set; }
```

Now I create an object of product class in my page and try to assign value in this property

```
string IconURL = FileHelper.BaseImageUrlPath + safeFileName.Replace(extension, "_i" + extension);
_Product.IconUrl = IconURL;
```

but value is not assigned to this property. Anyone can know what is the problem?

Comment: Did you try setting a property with a backing field to see if it assigns the string value?

Comment: what makes you think that "value is not assigned to this property"? what is the symptom? what happens? Perhaps most importantly: what does `_Product.IconUrl` report immediately after your code has executed?